# Inserting node between values in static list C

Tags: c, list, pointers, data-structures, struct

I have the following Structures created:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[15];
  int ID;
} Employee;

typedef Employee Item;

typedef struct {
  Item items[5];
  int size;
} List;
```

I take in values from a file which populate these fields using this function:

```
void Insert (Item I, int position, List *L){

  int i, LastPos;

  LastPos = Length(L)-1;
  if((LastPos) >= position){
    for(i = 0; i < (LastPos - position); i++){
      L->items[i-(LastPos+1)] = L->items[LastPos-i];
    }
  }

  L->items[position] = I;   
  L->size = L->size+1;
}
```

When the position variable is different (IE, one that hasn't been placed yet), then there are no issues, I am able to print out the values saved EG:

Insert Name Stacy ID 1928502 at position 0

Insert Name Jimmy ID 1290589 at position 1

When I call the print function for their name and ID number, they are printed out fine.

However, if I Inserted Jimmy at position 0, his information would be printed fine however, Stacy's would appear as a random memory location every time EG:the IDs become 32767.  Why does this happen when I override the position that has already been taken even though I have a loop which should reassign where the overridden information goes (one space back in the list).

Comment: Isn't typedef'ing Employee and typedefing Item redundant? 2nd typedef seems to do nothing except changing meaningful type name to non-meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets examine this expression:

```
L->items[i-(LastPos+1)]
```

If `Length()` returns `2` (the number of items currently in the array), then `LastPos + 1` should be `2`. Now when the loop starts, `i` is `0`, which means that `i - (LastPost + 1)` is equal to `0 - 2` which is `-2`. Not an index you would normally use in an array.

I suggest you go the other way around, by looping from the last item to the first:

```
for (int i = Length(L) - 1; i >= position; --i)
    L->items[i + 1] = L->items[i];
```

Comment: That's really interesting, I never thought of it this way.  I will give this a try.  Thanks!  EDIT: Yes this worked.  I was way over thinking the solution, I don't know why I just didn't count backwards. The more you know though!

Comment: @user2225940 Just updated my solution a little, so it will be able to better handle the case when the "list" is full. You still have to check for empty list of course.